# custom image search page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Please Help

I want to make a search page for images stored in media gallery of wordpress. This page contains a textbox in which user will enter the number of image. The matched image should display in the different tab of browser.

I made a raw html page in wordpress where i put the  which display a textbox but don't understand that where i have to write the php code to extract the images and how to show them.

Please give step by step instructions to solve the issue because i am beginner in wordpress.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function in functions.php for this and you can call that in your template

```
//In functions.php
if( ! ( function_exists( 'get_media_from_name' ) ) ) {
    function get_media_from_name( $postName ) {
        $args = array(
            'name'           => $postName,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',

        );
        $attachment = new WP_Query( $args );

        if ( $attachment)
            return $attachment;
        else
          return false;
    }
}


//In you template where you can call that function
$get_all_matched_attachments = get_media_from_name( $postName );

if ( $get_all_matched_attachments ) {
   foreach($get_all_matched_attachments as $get_all_matched_attachment){
       echo '<pre>';print_r($get_all_matched_attachment);
   }
}
```